# Delete pattern from a variable with sed

Tags: linux, bash, variables, sed

I am working with a script that has a variable called `PRODUCT_VERSION`.
The version comes with a dot (for example `6.0`).
I need to remove the dot and save the result in another variable.

So far I come with this, but it does not work correctly

```sh
PRD_VER=$(sed "s/$PRODUCT_VERSION/\.//g")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
$ PRODUCT_VERSION=6.0

$ PRD_VER=${PRODUCT_VERSION/.}

$ echo $PRD_VER
60
```

[Bash String Manipulation Examples](http://thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
NEW=$(sed 's/\.//g' <<<"$OLD")
```

or

```
NEW=$(echo "$OLD" | sed 's/\.//g')
```

However Mr Penny's answer is by far the best approach.