# GDB: How remove/replace pattern from a variable?

Tags: sed, gdb

I found the similar post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-sed-command) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048316/delete-pattern-from-a-variable-with-sed). But those solution seems like replacing the pattern from a file, not from a variable.

I have a function in a **gdb script**, which takes an address of a structure as **$arg0** and prints the fields of that structure like following,

Function:

```
define call_rb_node
  set $rb_left_child= (*(struct rb_node*)$arg0).rb_left
  set $rb_right_child= (*(struct rb_node*)$arg0).rb_right

  # printing fields
  p $rb_left_child
  p $rb_right_child
end
```

Output:

```
$1 = (struct rb_node *) 0xffff888236960f88
$2 = (struct rb_node *) 0xffff888236be92c8
```

I want to remove this **(struct rb_node *)** from both **$rb_left_child** and **$rb_right_child**. I want my output to be like

```
$rb_left_child = 0xffff888236960f88 
$rb_right_child = 0xffff888236be92c8
```

I was trying to use **sed** (don't know if I have any other options) to do that, but it's not working, I tried the following approach, but it's not working

```
define call_rb_node
  set $rb_left_child= (*(struct rb_node*)$arg0).rb_left
  set $rb_right_child= (*(struct rb_node*)$arg0).rb_right

  set $rb_left_child = $(sed /(struct rb_node *) /d $rb_left_child)

  # printing fields
  p $rb_left_child

end
```

I'm getting the following error

> Error in sourced command file:
>   No symbol "sed" in current context.

I replace the line like this,

```
shell echo set \$left_child=$(sed '/(struct rb_node *) /d' "$rb_left_child") > gdb.tmp
source gdb.tmp

p $left_child
```

but keep getting the following error,

> Error in sourced command file: gdb.tmp:1: Error in sourced command file:
>   A syntax error in expression, near `'.

please help.

Comment: Please don't tag with unnecessary/unrelated tags. This has nothing to do with the Linux kernel.

Comment: I guess you may use `rb_left_child="${rb_left_child/(struct rb_node \*) /}";` and `rb_right_child="${rb_right_child/(struct rb_node \*) /}";`, see [demo](https://rextester.com/GIVB6009)

Comment: A call to sed or other shell commands might be needed in some cases, but for this, try the gdb command `printf "$rb_left_child = %p\n", $rb_left_child`